# How to move some data to another tab based on specific column criteria

Tags: google-apps-script

Im currently using this code to move some rows if Column 6 contains "NA"

```
function MoveNA() {

    var s, targetSheet, found;
    var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var allsheets = s.getSheets();
    for(var s in allsheets){
    var s = allsheets[s];

    // Stop iteration execution if the condition is meet.
    if(
       (s.getName() == "Search") || 
       (s.getName() == "xx") || 
       (s.getName() == "NA")|| 
       (s.getName() == "Inventory") 
      ) continue;

    targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
        .getSheetByName("NA"),

    found = 0,
    s.getDataRange()
        .offset(1, 0)
        .getValues()
        .forEach(function (r, i) {
            if (r[5] == 'NA') {
                sourceRange = s.getRange((i + 2) - found, 1, 1, s.getLastColumn());
                targetSheet.appendRow(sourceRange.getDisplayValues()[0])
                s.deleteRow((i + 2) - found);
                found += 1;
              SetFormulasNA();
            } 
        })
}
}
```

I don't know how to update the code in order to move only the data in Columns: B, K,L,M,N,O,P

I want to copy as Values, not the formulas

All other data in the source row I don't want to move

Any help please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated your code to include cols you want to copy values from. See `dataColumns` array. It is a **1** based array, meaning, col B is 2, and so on. This only copies values into destination sheet and doesn't delete rows from source sheet.

```
function MoveNA() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  // destination sheet
  var desSheet = ss.getSheetByName('NA');

  // sheets to exclude
  var excludes = ['Search', 'xx', 'NA', 'Inventory'];

  // which cols to copy values from
  var dataColumns = [2, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16];

  // copy values
  sheets.forEach(function(sheet) {
    // check sheet is not in excludes
    if (excludes.indexOf(sheet.getName()) != -1) return;

    var found = 0;
    sheet
      .getDataRange()
      .getValues()
      .forEach(function(row, i) {
        // check condition
        if (row[5] == 'NA') {
          row.forEach(function(val, j) {
            if (dataColumns.indexOf(j + 1) != -1) return;
            row[j] = '';
          });
          desSheet.appendRow(row);
          // delete source row
          // sheet.deleteRow(i + 1 - found);
          // found += 1;
        }
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: Im getting The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid. (line 34, file "Move to NA")

Comment: and I DO need delete rows from source sheet. once is moved pls

Comment: test new code, if it works, enable delete code by uncommenting

Comment: I'm still getting The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid. (line 38)

Comment: strange. try again now

Comment: Probably that is due to the `offset` call. That specific error can be flagged on a `Range` call after the actual offending call is performed. Similar to this one: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/68062620

Comment: Hi, now im getting The number of rows in the data does not match the number of rows in the range. The data has 0 but the range has 1, I believe the problem is in .setValues(rows); because that line paints when the error ocurres

Comment: try again now!!

Comment: I got The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid. (line 37 again ;(

Comment: try updated code. also check your sheets as well. i see no error in code.

Comment: This code is working, the only problem is, in target sheet it paste the data in cols A-G and I need to paste in the same columns as the source

Comment: Its working now !!! ... but I uncommented rows 32 and 33 so it deletes the row from source tab, and im getting Those rows are out of bounds. (line 32 ... please help me to fix this, I appreciate very much your help !

Comment: try now. didn't update delete index code by mistake